# Using python print max and min values and date associated with the max and min values

Tags: python, max

I am new to programming and am trying to write a program that evaluates and prints the max AVE.SPEED value and the date associated with that value from a csv file. 
This would be an example of the file data set:

```
   STATION  DATE        AVE_SPEED
0    US68   2018-03-22  0.00
1    US68   2018-03-23  0.00
2    US68   2018-03-24  0.00
3    US68   2018-03-26  0.24
4    US68   2018-03-27  2.28
5    US68   2018-03-28  0.21
6    US10   2018-03-29  0.04
7    US10   2018-03-30  0.00
8    US10   2018-03-31  0.00
9    US10   2018-04-01  0.00
10   US10   2018-04-02  0.02
```

This is what I have come up with so far but it just prints the entire set at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'data_01.csv')
max1 = df['AVE_SPEED'].max()
print ('Max Speed in MPH: ' + str(max1))
groupby_max1 = df.groupby(['DATE']).max()
print ('Maximum Average Speed Value and Date of Occurance: ' + str(groupby_max1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial average speed max is correct in pandas.

To find the corresponding date, I would do the following:

```
mport pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'data_01.csv')
max1 = df['AVE_SPEED'].max()
print ('Max Speed in MPH: ' + str(max1))
date_of_max = df[df['AVE_SPEED'] == max1]['date'].values[0]
```

Effectively, you're creating another dataframe where any "AVE_SPEED" must equal the max speed (it should be a single row unless there's are multiple instances of the same max speed). From there, you return the 'date' value of that dataframe/row.

You can then print/return the max velocity and corresponding date as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a non-pandas approach to this as a lot of new programmers focus on learning pandas instead of learning python -- especially here it might be easier to understand what plain python is doing instead of using a dataframe:

```
with open('data_01.csv') as f:
    data = f.readlines()[1:]  # ditch the header
    data = [x.split() for x in data]  # turn each line in to a list of its values
    data.sort(key=lambda x: -float(x[-1]))  # sort by the last item in each list (the speed) ascending
    print(data[0][2])  # print the date (index 2) from the first item in your sorted data
```